# External CSS affecting ("bleeding" into) shadow DOM with Polymer

Tags: javascript, html, css, polymer

I must be missing something, but I can't figure it out what. I have simple custom element implemented with polymer:

```
<polymer-element name="test-elem">

    <template>
        <content></content>
        <div id="container">
            <div class="deepinside">
            TECK ... CHEST
            </div>
        </div>
    </template>

    <script>
        Polymer('test-elem', {
            applyAuthorStyles: false,
        });
    </script>

</polymer-element>
```

I then use it in a simple page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="en">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8" />

    <script src="libs/polymer.min.js"></script>

    <link rel="import" href="test-elem.html">

    <style>
    .deepinside { color: red; }
    </style>

</head>
<body>
    <test-elem>Hi</test-elem>
</body>
</html>
```

The content of the element's inner `div` (with `class="deepinside"`) is displayed in red. If I understand correctly, this shouldn't happen (see [this doc](http://www.polymer-project.org/articles/styling-elements.html#inheriting--resetting-outside-styles)). Note that I explicitly declared `applyAuthorStyles: false` in the element's constructor (it shouldn't be necessary, cause it is the default behavior). I don't understand why the external CSS is affecting an element in the shadow DOM. I've even tried specifying the `shadowdom` attribute explicitly in the element's definition, but the result is the same.

What am I missing?

FWIW, I'm running Chrome Version 31.0.1650.57 on OS X 10.7.5.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is an [known limitation of the Shadow DOM polyfill](http://www.polymer-project.org/platform/shadow-dom.html#known-issues). It does a pretty good job of preventing component styles from bleeding out, but it doesn't do the same for the other way around.

[Here's](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/rJsol) a codepen for your use case. It works as you intend in Chrome 33.0.1717.0 canary (for which Polymer doesn't polyfill Shadow DOM), but not in 31.0.1650.57.