# External style is bleeding into my Polymer component's local DOM

Tags: css, web-component, polymer-1.0, shadow-dom, polyfills

In my index.html, I'm importing my [Polymer](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/) custom element and linking the bootstrap stylesheet. If I inspect my custom element and its local DOM, I see that the bootstrap style is bleeding onto it. Is it because the shadow DOM polyfill of [Polymer](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/) ([shady DOM](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/articles/shadydom.html)) does not support encapsulation?

I have tried setting the [Polymer](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/) global DOM setting to `"shadow"`, but that didn't help (maybe because I'm using Safari and THAT it does not support shadow DOM yet, but I have linked the full [WebComponents](http://webcomponents.org) library, so it's supposed to polyfill that).

Searching on SO, I found this question: [External CSS affecting ("bleeding" into) shadow DOM with Polymer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20160798/external-css-affecting-bleeding-into-shadow-dom-with-polymer), but it is related to version 0.5 of [Polymer](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/), so I don't know how relevant it is for me right now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Known limitations
>
> - CSS encapsulation is limited.

This is a [known limitation](http://webcomponents.org/polyfills/shadow-dom/) of the Shadow DOM polyfill.

Answer (score 2):

Shadow DOM is not enabled by default in Polymer 1.0. This is because not all browsers currently support shadow DOM and it is incredibly hard to polyill so they didn't want people to experience different appearances in different browsers. You can turn this on however. See [here](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/settings.html) for how to do this. More information on this [here](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/migration.html#local-dom-template) and [here](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/#roadmap)

Comment: As I said in the description of my question, I have already tried enabling the shadow dom, but it didn't help. It might be because shadow DOM isn't supported in Safari yet and that encapsulation can't be implemented via a polyfill.

Answer (score 0):

Imagine the Shady DOM implementation something like jQuery plugin.
when a plugin adds new elements to you DOM the are no encapsulated in any way.

you can force Polymer to work with shadow DOM but pay attention that it is not fully supported and the polyfill webcomponents.js is doing a heavy lifting to make it work, so the performance is no optimal.

Comment: If at least the web components.js polyfill provided encapsulation I would be happy, but according to my tests it doesn't. It's confusing since the Polymer doc says: "Shadow DOM (and its approximation via Shady DOM) bring much needed benefits of scoping and style encapsulation to web development, making it safer and easier to reason about the effects of CSS on parts of your application. Styles do not leak into the local DOM from above, and styles do not leak from one local DOM into the local DOM of other elements inside.".

Comment: Source: https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/styling.html#xscope-styling-details

Comment: I suggest to work with some styling naming convention.